# org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException at query iterating

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to localize a bug in the following code snippet:

```
Query bookLogs = session.createQuery("FROM BookLog log");
for (Iterator it = bookLogs.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
  BookLog bookLog = (BookLog) it.next();
  bookNo = bookLog.getNo();
  ...
  session.delete(bookLog);
  session.flush();
}
```

Following exception occurs infrequently at bookLog.getNo():

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [de.store.Books.BookLog#2343]
```

I suppose a conflict at deleting db entry while iterator will not be adjusted by calling it.remove().

BookLog does not reference any tables and its mapping is accordingly simple.

Comment: why you are casting iterator object to book ? Instead you can try BookLog bookLog = (BookLog) it.next();

Comment: is it because you are trying to remove someting that is not there? I suppose it would return a NULL

Comment: and what is `bookNo`?

Comment: @Antoniossss Integer bookNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Query.interate()` returns proxy iterator, only `id` of entities are fetch.

> Executes 1+N SQL queries. The first query only returns the identifier of all the records and when the returned iterator is iterated then each time a separate SQL query is executed that contains a WHERE clause like WHERE id=N. If the records are present in cache then the first query is executed and the rest N queries are not executed and records are obtained from cache.

So this is concurrent modification problem. While you execute your query

```
for (Iterator it = bookLogs.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
```

given `BookLog` exist and its `id` is returned into iterator. While iterating, for every

```
 bookNo = bookLog.getNo()
```

separate `SELECT` query is performed, but on that point, whole table could has been modified by another concurrent action. Row with given `id` does not exist anymore, and exception is thrown. 
To avoid that you would have to use either proper `transaction-isolation` or use `Query.getResultList()`. This will return all results in single query. However, there is no guarantee (again) that when you will try to `delete` returned entity, it will still be in the database.